# How do i get rid of lots of horses?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In *Minecraft*, my friend built a horse spawning system to get many horses of one color. When he was done, there were a lot of excess horses which are now roaming my land. The horses are causing frame rate issues, lowering my FPS.

The horses are spread out across the land. Is there a way that I can get rid of all the horses, without killing the horses I have in my stable?

In case anyone needs visuals on what the land looks like:

[image: Horses]

Comment: Is it too much work to just run around a bit with a sword? How many horses are we talking, exactly?

Comment: If you just wanna have some fun......TNT and maybe Dyn-o-mite.

Comment: Your problem does not seem that much of a problem... How many horses do you have so that they cause noticeable lag (that other mobs do not)? How did you get so many horses?

Comment: @Jasarien Hundreds.

Comment: Can you add a picture?

Comment: @SamuelKoch How did you get so many horses? Surely you had a reason to do that, if you are opposed to slaying them now, right?

Comment: @BakedPotato http://imgur.com/iP4nGBU, this is only a portion of it.

Comment: @OrcJMR, my friend built a horse spawning machine, with no disposal mechanism, he wanted lots of horses of a certain color.

Comment: @SamuelKoch Oh... I'm afraid there is no way, if horses wander around like that - just manual slaughter. A script in a world editor program will do that, but hardly anything else.

Comment: Build a stone dome encasing your stable, cover the island with lava! Profit!

Comment: @Sconibulus What a creative answer!

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is get the mod "[Single Player Commands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-162-single-player-commands-v49-official-download-spc-noclip/)", in this mod, you can use a command called /butcher which you can use to kill mobs within a specified radius. I would say use a small radius and kill the surrounding horses that are further away from the stable. After that you can manually kill the rest. Also, the good thing about this mod is that you can back up your minecraft.jar and worlds so that you can then easily just uninstall the mod after you are done. If the above doesn't work then try fire...

Happy killing!

Comment: I always feel bad killing non-aggressive mobs. They're just all so cute and friendly...but I need feathers and chicken breast, dammit!

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I find that the fun part of killing innocent animals.... Am I corrupt?

Comment: @BakedPotato No, you're the only one that's normal.

Comment: This is a LAN world, SPC only works in Single Player.

Comment: @SamuelKoch LAN worlds work off of a single player world, find the CPU that is hosting the world, install it onto that CPU, kill, uninstall.Make sure that the user with the mod doesn't go on LAN otherwise it won't work. Also, from my experiences, some mods can work on LAN, just as long as everyone has it, otherwise it will be very glitchy

Comment: @BakedPotato I love how when you punch passive animals they start crazily running around in circles xD